# MVC3 - How do I pass a model reference with RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a login screen. When the login fails I don't want to return to that same screen with something like this:

```
return View(model);
```

What I would like to use is the following to take me to another screen:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

But how can I pass the model? I see some suggestions but these are related to MVC2. Is there some new feature with MVC3 that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Using the RedirectToAction method is basically calling Repsonse.Redirect(Server.Transfer, I always got those mixed up...but anyways).  In order to get the ViewModel to that redirected action, you would have to send the parameters of the model in the URL string

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new {prop1 = something, prop2 = something...etc});
```

However, there is no reason you cannot leverage off of TempData dictionary to maintain the ViewModel and not pass it in the URL parameters.

```
TempData["ViewModelItem"] = myViewModel;
Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

public ActionResult Index(){
   var model = (ViewModelType)TempData["ViewModelItem"];
}
```

**NOTE** The above code does not take into account null reference or type checking on the TempData item, which you would want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MVCContrib strongly typed redirect to action: [link](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RedirectToAction)

```
 public ActionResult PayWithCreditCard(int id, Buyer user)
        {
            return this.RedirectToAction<AuctionController>(x => x.Pay(user, id));
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to pass the model to RedirectToAction, as all this method does is to generate HTTP 301. This is NOT an equivalent of Server.Transfer.

You can use Html.Partial() to render a common control passing a certain model, or Html.Action() [see: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx]

It is considered outside of the proper design to call a controller method directly from another controller method. If you have some common functionality you want to reuse in multiple controllers then you should refactor it out to a separate entity (a service, maybe).

---

You might also want to taker a look at 13. Use PRG Pattern for Data Modification:
http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx

Comment: If RedirectToAction is not the right thing to do...what is?  How do you "go to another controller/action and pass the viewmodel"?